# Android: Can't figure this exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is my exception log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:587)
        at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:937)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5541)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1951)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1712)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It happens after I click on button. I can debug the onClick event to see that it performs as expected and replace a view in GroupView container, with add and remove View.

I got no place in code where I use `GestureDetector`, nor I use any external library.

I am working in Bluestacks and appcompact v7:22.2.0

Any ideas what can it be? Or what else can I test?

My click listener code:

```
    fancyCoverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Command command = Factory.inject(lobbyModel.items.get(position).commandClass);
            command.execute();
        }
    });
```

The thread dump from debugger

```
<1> main@831927632808" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at myClass.onItemClick(LobbyScreen.java:47)
      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
      at android.widget.Gallery.onSingleTapUp(Gallery.java:960)
      at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:568)
      at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:937)
      at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5541)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1951)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1712)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
      at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5721)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java:-1)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:-1)
```

### [Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649453/1129332)

Comment: post the code of your `onClick`

Comment: @njzk2 I added it. How ever I debug and saw no exception in it.

Comment: You don't use a touch listener either?

Comment: what does this do? You mention manipulating views. Do you remove views directly from the AdapterView?

Comment: @njzk2 No, I got my own framework where screens are added to shared container. In this code I remove the root view of the current screen and moving to the new one. In debug I see that the new screen is been initialized(its layout been successfully inflated). Also I only got one Activity in my project.

Comment: @Simas I added debug dump for my click listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing on an Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier system? It looks like an Android bug that was fixed in Jelly Bean.

Here's the [ICS code](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=ics-mr1-release#585):

```
// Hold the event we obtained above - listeners may have changed the original.
mPreviousUpEvent = currentUpEvent;
mVelocityTracker.recycle();
mVelocityTracker = null;
```

And here's the [Jelly Bean code](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=jb-mr0-release#585):

```
// Hold the event we obtained above - listeners may have changed the original.
mPreviousUpEvent = currentUpEvent;
if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
    // This may have been cleared when we called out to the
    // application above.
    mVelocityTracker.recycle();
    mVelocityTracker = null;
}
```

See how Jelly Bean is now testing `mVelocityTracker` for `null`? I think that's where your crash happened.

It looks like this bug has been encountered a number of other times, appears specific to ICS:

- [Null pointer Exception: GestureDetector.onTouchEvent for custom gallery in android for ICS 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260127/null-pointer-exception-gesturedetector-ontouchevent-for-custom-gallery-in-andro)
- [NullPointerException while working with GestureDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290802/nullpointerexception-while-working-with-gesturedetector)
- [Android TextView NullPointerException with onTouchListener and onClickListener on 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992621/android-textview-nullpointerexception-with-ontouchlistener-and-onclicklistener-o)
- [NullPointerException in GestureDetector.onTouchEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376956/nullpointerexception-in-gesturedetector-ontouchevent)

Comment: I added links to other related questions; you can look through those answers.

Comment: I got the exact same error log, it is a random crash that I got only once for now but it did not happen on ICS, it happened on Kitkat so the modification above cannot be the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @rhashimoto I added a work around for old versions. Simply overriding the view class and adding a try catch.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    catch (Exception ignored){
        return true;
    }
}
```

It might be not the best solution, but it solved the problem for me.